# прекращение работы Microsoft visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

При попытке обновить таблицу в бд в microsoft visual studio 2017 вылетает из программы, после захода в программу созданная таблица исчезает (скорее всего потому, что она не сохранилась).

```
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3
  Сигнатура проблемы 01:    devenv.exe
  Сигнатура проблемы 02:    15.8.28010.2050
  Сигнатура проблемы 03:    5bda1fc3
  Сигнатура проблемы 04:    PresentationFramework
  Сигнатура проблемы 05:    4.7.3081.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 06:    5b1890fa
  Сигнатура проблемы 07:    fbb
  Сигнатура проблемы 08:    5b
  Сигнатура проблемы 09:    N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Код языка:    1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А мне как понять, в чём ошибка? Для этого я и задал вопрос, может кто-нибудь с подобным сталкивался.

Comment: А что за база используется? Такая хрень бывает с Access, если драйвера обоих версий стоят.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло сначала сохранить (обновить) пустую таблицу, а потом уже редактировать её и сохранять изменённую версию.